# Two nearly identical transforms, first one works, second one not

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm writing a script to transform some XML and I've got two templates that would seem to be nearly identical. The first one works. When I have some original XML

```
<heading>Clinical Presentation</heading>
```

it becomes

```
<title>Clinical Presentation</title>
```

The second instance does not work. I always have the "ul" tags in the output rather than "listing" tags.

Does anyone know why this might be?

```
<xsl:template match="heading">
    <title>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </title>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul">
    <listing type="dash">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </listing>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: There aren't any `<ul>` elements in your original XML. Show us what these look like.

Comment: Sorry, I've actually identified the problem. The "ul" tags are embedded in CDATA tags, so they are not found. The "heading" tags are not so embedded. I'll have to put this transform in my second step XSLT.

Comment: Chad, your comment prompted me to look at my original XML, after which I remembered the CDATA embedding. That's worth a point.

Comment: So, do you still have a question, then? If not, please close the question or answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this question myself. Posting for the benefit of others. The original XML had the "ul" nodes wrapped in CDATA tags, making them inaccessible to the transform. The "heading" tags were not so embedded. The solution was to have a second transform to handle those nodes that were inside CDATA in the original XML.